# React: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs

Even though I assigned every child a key, I keep getting this error message.

```
function BertScoreSentence({sentence}: BertScoreSentenceProps) {

let content: JSX.Element[] = []
sentence.words.forEach((word) => {
    content.push(
        <>
            <span key={word.id}>
                {word.text}
                {bertscores && wordId >= 0 && word.id === bertscores[wordId][3] && isSummaryWord !== visualizeSummary && (
                    <>(s: {bertscores[wordId][4].toFixed(2)})</>
                )}
            </span>
            &nbsp;
        </>
    )
})

return (
    <p id={prefix + "" + sentence.id} className={className}>
        {content}
    </p>
)
```

}

I guess something is wrong with using <> or using span?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<React.Fragment key={word.id}>
                {word.text}
                {bertscores && wordId >= 0 && word.id === bertscores[wordId][3] && isSummaryWord !== visualizeSummary && (
                    <>(s: {bertscores[wordId][4].toFixed(2)})</>
                )}
            &nbsp;
</React.Fragment>
```

if you're keen about fragments

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments

Answer (score 0):

The key must be in the *top-most* React element returned - if you wrap it inside a fragment, React won't be able to tell.

I'd wrap the `&nbsp;` in a `<span>` and push it to `content` too:

```
const content = sentence.words.flatMap((word) => [
    <span key={word.id}>
        {word.text}
        {bertscores && wordId >= 0 && word.id === bertscores[wordId][3] && isSummaryWord !== visualizeSummary && (
            <>(s: {bertscores[wordId][4].toFixed(2)})</>
        )}
    </span>,
    <span key={word.id + 'space'}>&nbsp;</span>
]);
```